# How to disable "This file can harm your computer" chrome browser message while downloading a JAR file?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue while downloading JAR file using Selenium WebDriver chrome. Below are the codes I have tried found from different threads available on stackoverflow and none of them worked.

Example 1 -

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); 
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Example 2 -

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I am using ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 on Windows 10.

Is there any change in latest chromedriver or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow jar downloads. Use another webdriver.

Comment: Which browser should I use then? I tried with firefox but it always asks where to save the file. Is there anything else I need to provide for firefoxoptions?

Comment: Try with opera and ie.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you should not be testing files download functionality via the web browser as it's basically verification of browser functionality, not the functionality of the application under test.

I believe you should rather get [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) or [src attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/src) of the element you want to download and obtain it using [OkHTTP library](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) which is a transitive dependency of [Selenium Java Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java).

If your site requires authentication you could fetch [cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) from the browser instance and pass them to [OkHttp Request.Builder](https://gist.github.com/tsuharesu/cbfd8f02d46498b01f1b)

Comment: I am not testing file download as a functional but achieve end goal for my test, I need to download this file.